# What is the subject and predicate in the sentence "What time is the meeting?"

Tags: sentence, subjects, predicate

What is the subject and predicate in the sentence "What time is the meeting?"

I think subject here is "the meeting" and predicate "what time is". Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is a question.  To understand the structure, you can replace the question with the corresponding statement

> What time is the meeting? → The meeting is {what time}

Where {what time} would be replaced by an expression (such as a preposition phrase or an adverb) giving the time.

In this "canonical" form you can see that the subject is "The meeting" and the predicate is "is {what time}". In general predicates in questions are not written with the verb in initial position, and may be split up:  "Why did you play chess on the bus?"  Subject "you", Predicate "did play chess on the bus why"  (but not in that order).